# What's stopping z-index having an effect on these elements?

Tags: css, z-index

With the following code, I would expect the `<li>` elements to appear underneath the button when toggled. I can't figure out why this isn't the case—could someone shed some light on it?

```js
$('#switch').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#switch {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 1;
}

li {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.open li {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container open">
    <button id="switch">Click</button>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` does not take effect until the element has a position value of something other than `static`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to works needs to declare a position:

```js
$('#switch').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 1;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.open li {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container open">
  <button id="switch">Click</button>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepted this answer, as it's more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) with `position: absolute;`, `position: relative;`, or `position: fixed`.